# what is the algorithm complexity difference between batch and stochasitc gradient descent

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Batch gradient descent is      : `θj:=θj+α∑(yi-h(xi))xji`     for every `j`.

Stochastic gradient descent is :

```
loop
{  
   for i=1 to m,
   {
       θj:=θj+α(yi-h(xi))xji   for every j.
   }
}
```

I am curious about the complexity difference between two algorithms. I think the complexity is the same! Both are O(m*n), but batch gradient is m*n, and stochastic is n*m, just a different order, am i right?

Comment: Your batch gradient descent has an unbound variable (i).

Answer (score 2):

A) That is not how you would do SGD. You would pick "i" at random, or shuffle the data on each round.

B) You are only correct if you decide that you will do only a fixed number of epochs through the data.

In reality, you would want to keep running the algorithm until you converged to a solution. [SGD and GD have different rates of convergences](http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/compstat-2010.pdf), and it is not as simple as "the runtime is big O(f(x))". Each method takes a different amount of time to reach different goals. These further change depending on your loss function and other factors.

GD is not used in practice because there are better alternatives if you are going to perform only one update per epoch.

C) "m*n, and stochastic is n*m, just a different order, am i right?" That would be correct if your big O statement was correct.

D) you forgot to include the dimension of the problem in you big O.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic complexities of the two methods are in some sense the same.  If you run through both for multiple iterations of the outer loop, you asymptotically do the same amount of work.  The difference is in how the methods behave practically.

Typically, stochastic gradient descent is used as a way to deal with a really large training set. Suppose you have a billion items in your training set.  Batch gradient descent needs to go through all billion items for each time it updates the model parameters (theta).  Stochastic gradient descent continually makes progress on fitting the model parameters (albeit in smaller increments) for each training set item processed.

If your training dataset is very large and you don't have any bias in its ordering, you can (as you show) simply repeatedly loop through the dataset in order.  The fact that consecutive runs through the dataset are not using different orders shouldn't be a problem in practice.